# React Native , unable to add item in cart by using react -redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

I created a cart screen and list of items using react native and redux, but when I click buy item is not adding in cart and it's also not showing any error

Below is my code where I store list of items

Jeans.js

```
class Jeans extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <FlatList
          data={this.props.items}
          key={(items) => items.id.toString()}
          numColumns={2}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <CardBuyItem>
              <Image style={styles.image} source={item.image} />
              <View style={styles.detailContainer}>
                <Text style={styles.title}>{item.title}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.subTitle} numberOfLines={1}>
                  {item.subTitle}
                </Text>
                <Text style={styles.price}>Rs {item.price}</Text>
              </View>
              <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.props.addToCart(item.id)}>
                <View style={styles.buy}>
                  <Text>Buy Once</Text>
                </View>
              </TouchableHighlight>
            </CardBuyItem>
          )}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    items: state.clothes.jeans,
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    addToCart: (id) => dispatch(addToCart(id)),
  };
};
```

Below is my code of cart screen where items should added when user click by

cart.js

```
class Cart extends Component {
  render() {
    let addedItems =
      this.props.items && this.props.items.length ? (
        <FlatList
          data={this.props.items}
          key={(items) => items.id.toString()}
          numColumns={2}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <View>
              <Image style={styles.image} source={item.image} />
              <View style={styles.detailContainer}>
                <Text style={styles.title}>{item.title}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.subTitle} numberOfLines={1}>
                  Quantity: {item.quantity}
                </Text>
                <Text style={styles.price}>Rs {item.price}</Text>
              </View>
              <TouchableOpacity>
                <View style={styles.buy}>
                  <Text>Remove</Text>
                </View>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          )}
        />
      ) : (
        <View style={styles.emptyContainer}>
          <Text style={styles.empty}>There is Nothing in your Cart</Text>
        </View>
      );

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.order}>
          <Text style={styles.orderText}>You Order:</Text>
        </View>
        <View>{addedItems}</View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    items: state.addedItems,
  };
};
```

And below is my code reducer and action

reducer.js

```
export default function ClothesReducer(state = initialstate, action) {
  if (action.type === ADD_TO_CART) {
    let addedItem = state.jeans.find((item) => item.id === action.id);
    let existed_item = state.addedItems.find((item) => action.id === item.id);
    if (existed_item) {
      addedItem.quantity += 1;
      return {
        ...state,
        total: state.total + addedItem.price,
      };
    } else {
      addedItem.quantity = 1;
      let newTotal = state.total + addedItem.price;

      return {
        ...state,
        addedItems: [...state.addedItems, addedItem],
        total: newTotal,
      };
    }
  } else {
    return state;
  }
}
```

action.js

```
import { ADD_TO_CART } from "./ClothesActionType";

export const addToCart = (id) => {
  return {
    type: ADD_TO_CART,
    id,
  };
};
```

I'm trying to figure out what's wrong but can't find any error. Can someone help me to fix this?

Comment: What actions are dispatched, what data do they have and what changes do they make to the state? You can use redux devtools to check or even just console.log in middleware: `(store) => (next) => (action) => {
  console.log(
    'action',
    JSON.stringify(action, undefined, 2)
  );
  console.log(
    'state',
    JSON.stringify(store.getState(), undefined, 2)
  );
  setTimeout(() =>
    console.log(
      'new state:',
      JSON.stringify(store.getState(), undefined, 2)
    )
  );
  return next(action);
};`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In cart.js you should replace this

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    items: state.addedItems,
  };
};
```

With

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    items: state.clothes.addedItems,
  };
};
```

Comment: It worked Thanks, I had different list of items, like shirts, shoes, food how can I add them in `let addedItem = state.jeans.find((item) => item.id === action.id);` here

Comment: I suggest keeping all cloth in a single array but have a categories object for each item, to identify would make more sense. But it literally depends on how is your setup and what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: so in need to make and array inside initialstate and put all the items in it like `initialstat = {item:[jenas:{},shirts:{} ]}` and how I access them like `state.clothes.item(jeans)`?

Comment: suppose you have several clothes array like `jeans=[], shirts=[]` then make `initialstate = {items:[...jenas,...shirts]}`, each object of jeans or shirts could have a category prop which have default values jeans for jeans array and so on and then `state.clothes.items.filter(item=>item.category==='jeans)` to get jeans array

Answer (score 0):

You are mutating state, [here](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns) is some info on how to not do that.

I think your reducer should look something like this:

```
export default function ClothesReducer(
  state = initialstate,
  action
) {
  if (action.type === ADD_TO_CART) {
    let addedItem = state.jeans.find(
      (item) => item.id === action.id
    );
    let existed_item = state.addedItems.find(
      (item) => action.id === item.id
    );
    const addedItems = existed_item
      ? state.addedItems.map((item) =>
          item === existed_item
            ? { ...item, quantity: item.quantity + 1 }
            : item
        )
      : [
          ...state.addedItems,
          { ...addedItem, quantity: 1 },
        ];
    return {
      ...state,
      addedItems,
      total: state.total + addedItem.price,
    };
  } else {
    return state;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I had different list of items, like shirts, shoes, food how can I add them in let addedItem = state.jeans.find((item) => item.id === action.id); here?